# Passing Parameters to Comparators

Tags: c++, comparator

I would like to pass a map "m" as a parameter for a comparator to be used with the sort function.

```
bool comparator(const myType A, const myType B, map<Mytype,int> m){
      return m.find(A) < m.find(B); 
}
```

Note that the comparator changes depending on m. Now, how could I use such comparator with the sort function? When I try the code below the compiler complains about the number of arguments in the comparator function.

```
void SortingVector(vector<myType> V, map<myType,int> m){
     sort(V.begin(),V.end(),comparator); 
}
```

So what is the easiest way, using STD machinery to define such a parameterized comparator?

Answer (score 3):

Use a lambda closure:

```
void SortingVector(vector<myType>& V, const map<myType,int>& m){
    sort(V.begin(),V.end(), [&m](const myType& A, const myType& B) {
      return m.find(A) < m.find(B); 
    }); 
}
```

As a side note: I added various references, for both effectiveness and correctness, as your sort function otherwise would just sort a copied vector and throws it away after it ran out of scope.